# Submit ajax form without page refresh php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, submit

I have this form and ajax call in my index.php-

```
 <form method='post' id='saleForm' >
    <input type='text' name='addCustomer' class='addInput' id='adlastname' placeholder='customer last name'>
    <input type='text' name='addYear' class='addInput'  id='adYear' placeholder='year'>
    <input type='text' name='addMake' class='addInput'  id='adMake' placeholder='make'>
    <input type='text' name='addModel' class='addInput'  id='adModel' placeholder='model'>
    <input type='text' name='addGross' class='addInput'  id='adGross' placeholder='front gross'>
    <input type='hidden' name='Id' value='<?php echo $id;?>'>
    <input type='submit' name='subSale'  id='subSale' value='Save' >
</form>

<script>
    $("form").submit(function(e) {
    var url = "add.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.

$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url,
       data: $("form").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
       success: function(data)
       {
           alert(data); // show response from the php script.
       }
     });

e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
</script>
```

I am trying to submit it to the DB using add.php -

```
$cust = $_POST['addCustomer'];
$addMake = $_POST['addMake'];
$addModel = $_POST['addModel'];
$addYear = $_POST['addYear'];
$addGross = $_POST['addGross'];
$subSale = $_POST['subSale'];
$soldDate = date('m/d/yy');

if(isset($subSale)){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `$sold_table` ( `Id`,`Customer`, `Year`, `Make`, `Model`, `FrontGross`, `SoldDate` ) VALUES (NULL,'$cust', '$addYear', '$addMake', '$addModel', '$addGross', '$soldDate')";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo 'success!';
    } else {
       echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
}
```

When I click the Save button it shows the empty alert and the data isnt getting pushed for some reason.. Any idea where I am going wrong here? i know the Insert is correct as it works when I dont use the ajax call and just use the form action..

Comment: Well, what did you expect the output to be?

You're not echo-ing anything on success. So, does the data arrive in the database?

Comment: Yes just trying to get the data to the database

Comment: This at least explains the empty alert

Comment: Also, I wouldn't pass an Id to an insert query, but instead have MySQL do an auto_increment.

Comment: It is auto inc. I am passing it as Null

Comment: Yes, I saw that. However, you can just omit it and it will work. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Could you echo the $sql variable below the if-statement?

Comment: It then should turn up in the alert

Comment: The sql statement appears empty when i echo it

Comment: So it seems the problem is the if(isset($subSale)){} is the issue, when I remove it, it uploads fine..

Comment: Then $subsale isn't set apparently. Try dumping $_POST at the top of the script.

Comment: I see the problem. The Ajax request doesn't use the subsale button. Since it is submitted by jQuery.

Comment: Yep you are right! thank you

Comment: I'll summarize the solution in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using jQuery to submit the form, the submit button isn't used. Therefore it will turn up empty once PHP receives the posted data.
Your script is checking $subSale to perform the query, which now fails.

Try to supply a hidden input with the name SubSale and it wil work again. Another solution is to remove this entire if statement, as per your own suggestion.

```
if(isset($subSale)){
```